# Any way I can shorten the length of this date without having to run date()?

Tags: python, html, angularjs, django

I am working with django and using angularjs. I made a request which responded with an object containing the name, price and date this input was modified.

My html has the following `{{price_level.modified }}` providing me with `2018-01-16T10:15:34.401839Z`.

Here is the data that I am getting when I console.log the data

`created: "2017-06-02T05:01:17.803045Z"
fs_charge: 10
id: 595
locked: false
modified: "2018-02-06T07:36:21.517414Z"
moq: 30
moq_price: 60`

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: What do you want the date to look like?

Comment: `2018-02-06` would be good enough for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result appears to be a string in YYYY-mm-dd format with time, so just slice it.

```
{{price_level.modified[:10] }}
```

Comment: I thought this might work too, but nothing is showing up now when I load the page. I get one of these `angular.js:12722 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token ':' not a primary expression at column 22 of the expression [price_level.modified[:10]] starting at [:10]].`

EDIT: Fixed it. I just did .slice(0,10) instead haha Thank you!

Comment: Angular is not my expertise. Perhaps using JS `{{price_level.modified.slice(0, 10 }}`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want `YYYY-MM-DD` you could do a substring from position 0 through 9.

Example in Python `dateStr[:10]`